# Checking for empty string using .equals(), .isEmpty() and .length() in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am writing some code to check if two strings are anagrams, in Java. This is for the [Anagrams problem on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-anagrams/problem).

My code is failing only 1 of the 17 test cases, and I'm guessing it's due to invalid inputs. This is where my issue lies. At the very beginning of the method, I want to check if either input string is `null` or an empty string, and if it is, I return false.

This is the relevant code block -

```
private static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
        if( a == null || b == null || a.equals("") || b.equals("") ) {
            System.out.println("Inside");
            return false;
        }

        HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
```

The problem is, when I test this method with invalid inputs, like `"hello"` and `""`, the `if` block doesn't seem to execute. I've tried replacing the `.equals()` method with `.isEmpty()` and `.length() == 0`, but no matter which method I use, the `if` doesn't work.

Using JShell, I've checked that if I create an empty string with `""`, all these methods work -

```
jshell> String a = ""
a ==> ""

jshell> a.isEmpty()
$2 ==> true

jshell> a.length()
$3 ==> 0

jshell> a.equals("")
$4 ==> true

jshell> a == null
$5 ==> false

jshell> "" == ""
$6 ==> true

jshell>

jshell> "".equals("")
$7 ==> true

jshell> "".length()
```

Is there a reason why this way of checking for empty string won't work in an `if` block?

---

UPDATE - Complete code on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zjF3ccDb)

Comment: Maybe the invalid input is something like two spaces. Then your if statement is not executed. in this case you have to trim the input first.

Comment: Your code works for me. Could you show code with test cases?

Comment: Try with and operator ` if( (a == null && b == null) &&( a.equals("") && b.equals("")) ){...}`

Comment: @sawim I uploaded the complete code using a pastebin link. I don't have access to the failing test case (#8) because it's locked.

Comment: What if a and b are having just whitespaces instead of empty string? I am guessing you should be writing your if statement as 

a == null || b == null || a.trim().equals("") || b.trim().equals("")

Answer (score 0):

I see that you don't pass one test case, and it does not involve invalid inputs. You've missed one thing, you should take into consideration case sensitivity

```
a = a.toLowerCase();
b = b.toLowerCase();
```

Just make your strings lowercase after validation and it should be alright

Comment: I'm already converting the input to lowercase when I add it to the HashMap (lines 10-11 on pastebin), do I need to do it separately too?